# Dagger Injection in Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, dagger-2

I have a question on how I can get my instrumentation tests to work with my existing dagger project.

I have these classes

```
class Foo {
    @Inject Bar bar;

    @Inject
    Foo() {
        DaggerComponent.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

class Bar {
    @Inject DummyObj dummy;
    @Inject Context context;

    @Inject
    Bar() {
        DaggerComponent.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}

@Module
public class RealModule {
     @Provides
     public providesDummyObj(Context context) {
         return new DummyObj(context);
     }
}
```

The above code is not complete, but it is basically using the RealModule from an application. and it is running fine.

But now I want to have an instrumented test cases that executes tests from Foo, but with a Mocked context and DummyObj so the Foo and Bar class automatically picks up the mocked object; instead other than passing the mocked objects around?

```
class FooTest extends InstrumentationTest {
    @Mock DummyObj mDummyObj;
    @Mock Context context;
    @Inject Bar bar;

    @Override
    setup() throws Exception {
        DaggerComponent.getComponent().inject(this);
        MockitoAnnotation.initMocks(this);

        doReturn("test").when(mDummyObj).doSomething();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to override the `dummy` and `context` in my instrumentation test to provide an actually mocked object?

Helps appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that if you are mocking a context then it should be a unit test, not an instrumentation. You are making things difficult for yourself by not using constructor injection on your objects.  By doing so mocking your objects and passing them as constructor arguments to your SUT becomes easy (no need for dagger in this case), at present you cannot do this.  Only use field injection on Android classes like `Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` i.e. anything that you have no constructor control over.

Comment: unfortunately the project is quite convoluted (Imo) and is inherited and relies on field injections heavily. :(

Comment: I suppose you have 2 choices then, refactor : so the code is better, and easier to test and maintain, or : write test modules that extend your current modules, override the provides methods with `Mockito.mock(MyMockObject.class)` and another component that extends the current component, but uses you test modules - however, to me, this continues to be convolute as you put it. Note second approach would require a custom Android test runner and Application class.

Comment: So if I were to transfer the classes to constructor injection. The services would still rely on a production component with production object modules - how do the mocked objects be provided passed to the services for tests?

Comment: What is your SUT? I have suggested either option with hints of how you might do it if you don't use constructor injection. If your SUT is Bar in your example then you need field injection, as I said in my first comment, if not an Android framework class, then use constructor injection. Seems a bit pointless to mock a context when doing instrumentation tests that run using the Android SDK. As you're becoming more specific you're pseudo code is not really helping with an accurate answer or solution.

Comment: Thanks, I think I better off porting all classes without the constructor limitations to constructor injections. Then set the injection components (extended from the production component) providing necessary test modules on the SUT.